# Data wont insert into Database

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert data from a form to my database but it doesn't seem to work. I've put an echo after the insert query so I can verify that the data was inserted but it doesn't echo what I've written. Is there a problem with my query or any part of my php?

My PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stat_system";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$fname = $lname = $mname = $contact = $age = $attain = $course = $school = $position = $exp = $ref = $batchtxt = $hiredate = $prevbpo = $remarks = $nho = $nonbpo = $holdAttain = $holdPos = "";
$error_flag = 0;                   


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $holdAttain = (isset($_POST['cmbAttain']));
                $holdPos = (isset($_POST['cmbPosition']));

                if (!empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
                    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
                    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['middlename'])) {
                    $mname = $_POST['middlename'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['contact'])) {
                    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['age'])) {
                    $age = $_POST['age'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['cmbAttain'])) {
                    $attain = $_POST['cmbAttain'];
                }

                if(isset($_POST['school'])) {
                    $school = $_POST['school'];
                }

                if(isset($_POST['course'])) {
                    $course = $_POST['course'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {
                    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['remarks'])) {
                    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['nonbpo'])) {
                    $nonbpo = $_POST['nonbpo'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['prevbpo'])) {
                    $prevbpo = $_POST['prevbpo'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['ref'])) {
                    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['hiredate'])) {
                    $hiredate = $_POST['hiredate'];
                }

                if (isset($_POST['batchtxt'])) {
                    $batchtxt = $_POST['batchtxt'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['nho'])) {
                    $nho = $_POST['nho'];
                }

                if($error_flag == 0){
                    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO applicants (appID, appLastName, appFirstName, appMidleName, Age, appPhoneNumber, appBatch, appExperience, appRemarks, appPreviousBPO, appSchool, appCourse, appGraduate, appNonBPO, appPosition, appHireDate, appNHO, appReferrer)
                                                     VALUES (NULL, '$lname', '$fname', '$mname', $age, '$contact', $batchtxt, '$exp', $remarks, '$school', '$course', '$attain', '$nonbpo', '$position', $hiredate, $nho, '$ref')");
                       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#succModal').modal('show');
                        });
                        </script>";
                    $fname = $lname = $mname = $contact = $age = $attain = $course = $school = $batchtxt = $ref = $hiredate = $position = $exp = $prevbpo = $remarks = $nho = $nonbpo = $holdAttain = $holdPos = "";

                }
                else {
                    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                    print 'alert("Please fill in all the fields!")';
                    print '</script>';

                }
            }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

My HTML:

```
 <div id="addApplicant" class="addApp-marginleft" style="height:1000px">

        <form id="registration" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="index.php">
            <div class="row">
                <div  align="center">
                    <h3>Add Applicant</h3>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>First name:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input required type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small> Last name:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input required type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete="off" id="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lname;?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Middle name:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input required type="text" name="middlename" autocomplete="off" id="middlename" placeholder="middlename" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mname;?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Contact number:</small></label>
                <span id="errmsg"></span>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input required type="text" name="contactnum" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" placeholder="Contact number" id="contact" class="form-control" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $contact;?>"/>
                </div>
                <?php
                    echo '<script>';
                    echo 'function isNumber(evt) {';
                        echo 'evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;';
                        echo 'var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;';
                        echo 'if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {';
                            echo 'return false;';
                        echo '}';
                        echo 'return true;';
                    echo '}';
                    echo '</script>';
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Age:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input required type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="age" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $age;?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Graduate:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select required name="cmbAttain" id="cmbAttain" class="form-control" onChange="disableCmb();">
                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                        <option value="Yes" <?php if($holdAttain == "Yes") echo "selected"; ?>>Yes</option>
                        <option value="No" <?php if($holdAttain == "No") echo "selected"; ?>>No</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>School:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="school" autocomplete="off" id="school" placeholder="School" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $school;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Course:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="course" autocomplete="off" id="course" placeholder="Course" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $course;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Batch:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="batchtxt" autocomplete="off" id="batchtxt" placeholder="Batch" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $batchtxt;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Experience:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="exp" autocomplete="off" id="exp" placeholder="Experience" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $exp;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Previous BPO:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="prevbpo" autocomplete="off" id="prevbpo" placeholder="Previous BPO" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $prevbpo;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Non-BPO:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="nonbpo" autocomplete="off" id="nonbpo" placeholder="Non-BPO" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nonbpo;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Remarks:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="remarks" autocomplete="off" id="remarks" placeholder="Remarks" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $remarks;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Hire Date:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="date" name="hiredate" id="hiredate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $hiredate;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Position:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select required name="cmbPosition" id="cmbPosition" class="form-control" data-size="5" >
                        <option selected value="">Choose</option>
                        <option value="Customer Service Representative" <?php if($holdPos == "Customer Service Representative") echo "selected"; ?>>Customer Service Representative</option>
                        <option value="Image Enhancer" <?php if($holdPos == "Image Enhancer") echo "selected"; ?>>Image Enhancer</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>NHO:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="date" name="nho" id="nho" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $nho;?>">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Referrer:</small></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" name="ref" autocomplete="off" id="ref" placeholder="Name of Referrer" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ref;?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="btn-group " role="group" aria-label="...">
                        <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value="Submit" data-target="#succModal">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
  <div class="container">
     <!-- Register Success Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="succModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-body" align="center">

                      <p>REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Either look (and show us) for proper error message, or add debugging info along your code.

Comment: @J.Chomel It doesn't show me any error message, just doesn't insert the data to the database. Is it okay to have $.post() that passes multiple data? I think the main problem is just around there or my php.

Comment: echo `$sql` & run the query directly in mysql.It will show you the error

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I've totally changed the code now but it seems that it still doesn't work. It doesn't echo what I've placed when the insertion is successful so I think the problem is around my php code?

Answer (score 0):

use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST..

like:

```
$lname =  $_POST['lname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just at a glance, you're NULL tests should be seperated by `&&`, not `||`. The way you have it, it's only checking whether one (any) of them contain a value.

Answer (score 0):

There is some errors with you query, just replace it with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO applicants (appLastName, appFirstName, appMidleName, Age, appPhoneNumber, appBatch, appExperience, appRemarks, appPreviousBPO, appSchool, appCourse, appGraduate, appNonBpo, appPosition, appHireDate, appNHO, appReferrer) VALUES ('$lname','$fname','$mname',$age,'$con',$batch,'$exp','$rem','$prevbpo','$school','$course','$gradsit', '$nbpo', '$pos', '$hdate', '$nho', '$ref')";
```

here, there is no need to add appid as it is auto-incremented. Also there are some missing single quotes.

Comment: appHireDate type is date, should i still put '$hdate'?

Answer (score 0):

- Skip to send value `NULL` in your `insert` statement
- where you check whether $_POST is empty, if it is empty set $error_flag=1
- Inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` print $_POST

Hope this will help to debug. If still issue, check your error_log